# check loadHTMLFile url exists and if it has a div in it, if not, do nothing

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to detect a couple things from a url.

1. is it valid
2. does it have a specific div in it

   ```
   $url = 'http://www.google.com/aasdsasdfafddsgsagf';
   $dom = new DOMDocument;
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $request = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
   $DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

   $title = $DOMxpath->query("//span[@class='bluebar']")

   if(!$request || $title->length == 0){
       echo 'failed!!';
   }
   ```

I am trying to get this conditions:

if the page loads and it **does not** have the div - do nothing.

if the page does not load - do nothing.

Right now I am getting this error which stops everything that comes after it from running properly.

error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.google.com/aasdsasdfafddsgsagf): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in...
```

I still get the echo 'failed!!'.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem can be solved by suppressing the warning. This can be done by affixing `$dom->loadHTMLFile($url)` with the *[Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)* `@`.

```
$request = @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

In the example there is missing a semicolon after setting `$title`. That causes a `PHP Parse error`. This code will do what you want:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/aasdsasdfafddsgsagf';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$request = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url); // $request === false
$DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$title = $DOMxpath->query("//span[@class='bluebar']");

if(!$request || $title->length == 0){
    echo 'failed!!';
}
```